# TFS 2012 migration to clean installation of TFS 2015

Tags: team-foundation-server, live-migration

We want to move TFS 2012 to clean installation of TFS 2015. Are there any guides? The rough idea now is to execute in-place upgrade of TFS 2012 and than point TFS 2015 to this databases. There is only limited time where machines could be offline.

Answer (score 1):

We always do this.  The general idea is preform a full backup on the 2012 databases.  Create the new machine, Install SQL, import the Collection database files.  Then install fresh the new version of TFS and point to the new SQL server and let the upgrade convert the old database files.  Remember to export/import the Report encryption keys.

Comment: What do you mean by *"Then install fresh the new version of TFS and point to the new SQL server and let the upgrade convert the old database files."* Can you write you answer more detailed?

Answer (score 1):

First of all study the official docs at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/tfs/upgrade/upgrade.
Also take a look at the guidance at http://vsarupgradeguide.codeplex.com/. While dated it is very good in framing the process steps.

Upgrade may take a considerable amount of time: to succeed consider a dry run.
Also if you want have both the old and new instance running change the server id, otherwise the clients will be confused.